# Side Effects Detector for PHP

Tags: php, code-analysis, refactoring, phpstorm

As a backend developer working on a legacy code, I want to know the side effects of a piece of code.

> For example, I want to select a method of a class and be informed of
> what possible interactions it has with the Redis.

I want this (plugin, for example) to read a specific code and find the possible ways for this code to call a method from a specified class (Redis Client or Cache Service Interface or a third party class, for example).

> It's similar to what I do when reading a spaghetti code without
> automated tests; I read the code and search what it calls, and if I
> see a side effect I was looking for (like calling the Redis Client
> methods), I note them somewhere.

In the functional perspective (almost), I give it a piece of code in the codebase (a method, for example) and a class namespace (Redis Client namespace, for example) as inputs. I want it to give me the list of what methods of that class (Redis methods - get, set, push, pop, ....) could be called by the selected code and on what conditions.
Please look at the example on end for better clarification.

### Requirements

Must have:

1. Work on a PHP codebase
2. Don't run the code

Nice to have:

1. Be able to be used in PHPStorm - like a plugin

### Example

Imagine we have:

- A **Use Case** for adding an order needing the User Repository to
  find the user.
- The **User Repository** works with the Cache Service we have written.
- The **Cache Service** has been implemented using **Redis**.

Somewhere in the Use Case, it calls the User Repository's get method.
In that method, we have:

```
// Some code, maybe

if (<Cache Service> -> exists ($key)) {
    return <Cache Service> -> get ($key);
}

// Get the user from the DB

<Cache Service> -> set ($key, $user);

// The rest of the method
```

The Cache Service calls the Redis methods such as exists, get, set, etc.

When I select the method (execute, for example) in the Use Case calling the User Repository, as the piece of code, and the Redis Cinet namespace, used in the Cache Service, as inputs, I want to see the result like the below:

- *exists*: Use Case -> User Repository -> Cache Service line 16
- *get*: Use Case -> User Repository | if line 16 = true | -> Cache
  Service line 32
- *set*: Use Case -> User Repository | if line 16 = false | -> Cache
  Service line 256

(the names on the left are the names of the methods of the Redis Client, which I gave as one of the inputs (namespace))